# unable to get pubsub messages, 'pubsub:event' is not fired using stanza.io

Tags: ionic-framework, xmpp, ionic3, publish-subscribe, stanza.io

I am working with pubsub on ionic framework and i'm using stanza.io [library](https://github.com/legastero/stanza.io), i'm able to publish message and call getItems from node. but **'pubsub:event' is not fired**. i'm unable to get real-time message which is published on node by other users. my code is as below...

**publish**

```
this.client.publish("pubsub.dev1.internal", 'mynode', {
        json: {
          value: 'Any JSON content could go here'
        }
      }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(data)
        }
      });
  }
```

**getItems**

```
this.client.getItems("pubsub.dev1.internal", 'mynode', opts ,
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(data)
        }
      })
```

**pubsub:event**

```
this.client.on('pubsub:event', function (msg) {
      console.log("pubsub:event");
      console.log(msg);
    });
```

messages which are published are stored in server and when i call getItems i can fetch that messages, but the problem is **messages are not received on real-time using 'pubsub:event'**. can anyone help me to solve this?